# Getting System.Xml.XmlException error trying to re-add app server to our farm

Tags: upgrade, psconfig

We upgraded one of our servers with SP1, then July 2015 Cumulative updates but were getting errors. So we disconnected the server from farm and re-upgraded with no errors. But when we try to reattach the server to the farm we receive this strange error:

> Failed to connect to the configuration database.
>   An exception of type System.Xml.XmlException was thrown.  Additional exception information: Name cannot begin with the ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20. Line 1, position 15361.
>
> System.Xml.XmlException: Name cannot begin with the ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20. Line 1, position 15361.

I've tried with both farm and admin account. The passphrase was OK. Any idea what causes this issue?